# Deleting an Entity with related data and Cascading Deletes defined in SQLServer

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm getting the following error when I SaveChanges after Removing an entity that has related entities containing data in the context as well. (The entity I'm deleting has the unique Primary Key). I have Cascading Delete configured at the SQL Server database level for the relation between the primary key table and the foreign key table.

"The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not su...

The primary entity has its related data loaded explicitly prior to me removing the primary from the context. I assumed that EF and SQL Server would take care of the cascaded delete for me. If the related entity has no data the delete (of the primary entity) works fine. If there is data in the related entity, I get the error above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, I am using Database First, so, in my model, Cascading Delete is configured in the model as well. I am certain that Cascading delete works at the database level because I tested deleting a parent row and can see the child row's deleted automatically. I just can't seem to be able to delete a parent entity and have the child entities deleted as well.

Comment: It would be helpful to know a little bit more about your model.  How is the relationship defined?  What is the data type of the foreign key.  Regardless, there is a very good blog post by Arthur Vickers (part of the EF team) [here](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/06/02/deleting-orphans-with-entity-framework/) that explains this error is fairly great detail with regards to what is happening.  I have gone back to this blog post a number of times as I have worked with EF.

Comment: Not sure how to explain "how" the relationship is defined. I did it in the SSMS database diagrams designer. The key's data types are UniqueIdentifier (in SqlServer) and GUID in VS. Nice article. Still cant get cascading to work.

Comment: By "how the relationship is defined" I was more curious about the relationship's multiplicity (is it 1...Many or 0/1...Many)?  Regardless, I threw together a test project where I defined the cascading delete at the database level and the code worked as desired.  Whether or not I defined the cascading delete in the EF model didn't matter.  Of course, I am using the fluent API.  I tried to create the model using the designer route but something is off with my environment as it wouldn't let me use the designer.  How do you delete the entity in your code?  Can you paste a sample of that?

Comment: So, it seems that setting an entity's state to Deleted is not the same as Removing the entity, especially if the entity you're removing has child entities! I had been setting the State to Deleted instead of Removing. Apparently the Remove method sets the state of related entities to deleted as well.

Comment: Ah, yes.  EF has those little nuances.  In my experience, I have typically seen the exception when trying to delete a child entity that has a required dependency on the parent (read, the foreign key is non-nullable).  In this case, you cannot remove the child entity from the collection on the parent entity and save the parent entity (or else you will get the exception).  Instead, you have to actually delete the child entity outright.  Of course, if the child entity has a identifying relationship, this is not applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lesson is that EF has a learning curve. Keep exploring.

Anyway, I was "deleting" entities by setting the state to "Deleted" then calling SaveChanges. This seems to work fine if the entity has no related data. However, if you have an entity that has related "child" entities, you need to call Remove on the parent entity for the "delete" to cascade through the graph. Live and learn. I'm pretty sure this is the answer. I think for the time being I'm going to stop setting State for deletes and use Remove instead.